# Docker and host bridging

Tags: python, docker

How to bridge docker container and localhost service?

My service inside docker container cant talk with mongidb server, running on host machine

Comment: You should ask this question on ServerFault. StackOverflow is for programming questions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach)

Answer (score 0):

I too faced this situation. You can use your localhost services in docker.

```
Steps:
 1. In your MongoDb (or any service) conf file, bind that service with machine's ip ( not localhost or 127.0.0.1, it might look like 192.168.x.x) and restart it.
 2. In your docker, access service via given machine's ip.
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

As @David Maze pointed out, this is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach) for Mac and Windows machines, and [this Github issue](https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/264) contains a pending Linux feature that will make the solution work for Linux too. That answer says use `host.docker.internal` instead of `localhost` to access your host machine's IP from within your containers.